# Into how many languages has the Book of Mormon been translated?

Tags: lds, book-of-mormon, pearl-of-great-price, doctrine-and-covenants

I understand that the Bible, consisting of the Old and New Testaments, is the most translated book in the world.  It seems that giving the Word of God to all the world is considered part of the Great Commission.

Since the LDS church holds the Book of Mormon to be the Word of God, just like the Bible, what is the current total number of languages into which it has been translated.  I would also be interested in statistics for the Pearl of Great Price and the Doctrines and Covenants.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Currently, 150 million+ copies in any of 82 languages.](http://www.mormonnewsroom.org/ldsnewsroom/eng/background-information/the-book-of-mormon-another-testament-of-jesus-christ) (from the Mormon Newsroom)

> Since it was first published in English in 1830, the Book of Mormon
>   has been fully translated into 82 languages, and printed copies have
>   totaled more than 150 million.

I'll add a note that I've seen at least a dozen incomplete translations ("Selections from the Book of Mormon") into more obscure languages. Interestingly, I have also met people who, for existing translations, are assisting in making better translations for difficult languages like Farsi where current translations are lacking.

[This page on the LDS Store](http://store.lds.org/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/Product3_715839595_10557_22031_-1__195551) has 37 languages in the list for the Triple Combination, which includes the Book of Mormon, Doctrine and Covenants, and Pearl of Great Price.

As a side, [here's an interesting article](http://www.mormonnewsroom.org/article/understanding-the-process-of-publishing-the-book-of-mormon) about the publishing of the Book of Mormon.

Comment: I did find it amusing that you could select between 37 languages, and that there was also an option to select the color of the book--but there was only one color you could select.  As a Web Developer, you don't tell people there's a choice if there's only one option.  LOL

Comment: As of last week, there are now 109 languages, with Malay being the most recent.